# Hyper-V RCT enabling

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I'am working on fast backup solution for Hyper-V (same tool for ESXi 6.5 using CBT is already done).

My Hyper-Vs (one on Windows 10 config version 8.3 and one on the Windows Server 2019 config version 9) does not create Resilient Change Tracking files (*.mrt and *.rct) in virtual disk folder. I'm really stuck in this point. If I understand MS documentation correctly I need not to do any additional steps to enable Resilient Change Tracking on Hyper-V. I cannot understand why these files are not provided and what steps I need to do to enable it.

I have:
[image]

I expect:
[image]

Comment: What has your current troubleshooting and research shown you about this? What processes have you followed and how have they failed?

Comment: When giving more information, please use the EDIT button and add this information to the body of the question itself. This makes the question better and more clear and complete and means it's not necessary to read the comments in order to understand the problem.

Comment: @music2myear, thank you, sir. I am new here.

Comment: The unclear votes were because of the reasons noted in my initial comment. Questions are closed not to kill them, but to give them time to be improved. This question will be reopened shortly and should start getting answers if people with the appropriate knowledge and experience sees it.

Comment: @music2myear thank you, sir for your explanation.

Comment: Make sure your VM configuration version is 8 or higher in order for RCT to be enabled. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9654190c-41e6-4797-84f1-24696d9ce269/hyperv-how-to-enabledisable-rct-changetracking-using-wmi-

Answer (score 1):

MRT and RCT files are created in the default Virtual hard disk folder, not in the backup folder:

In my case, they are in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response. But unfortunately these files are missed for me :(